# Curvature of a one-pixel wide curve

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision, curve-fitting

I have a numpy array depicting a **one-pixel wide, discrete, connected** curve. This curve is obtained by the *Skeletonization* operation of image processing. I am trying to find the curvature of the above curve at an arbitrary point, to detect **bends/kinks** (which will have high curvature value).

I tried to implement the above using the [general formula for curvature](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Curvature.html). However, since this a pixelated, discrete curve, whose generating function is unknown, I tried to resort to using numpy `gradient` instead.

The problem I see with the above is that, since the curve is **one-pixel wide**, at any point the slope can be **only one of 0, 1 or *infinity***. As a result, the curvature values that I get are mostly meaningless or useless.

I am looking for some suggestion on where to start in order to get a smooth curve out of the above, so that I can calculate curvature in a more meaningful way. Can somebody suggest any mathematical operation or convolution that I can apply to achieve the same? Below is a representative binary image that I have.

[image: Curvature of One-pixel Wide Image]

**P.S.** I am very, very new to image processing, so references to standard algorithms (in math books) or library implementations would be very helpful.

Comment: Requesting some clarification: When you say you "have a numpy array depicting a one-pixel wide...curve", are you referring to the 2D array containing the skeletonized image, i.e. the picture you posted?  Or do you mean that you have a 1D array containing a segment that you have already extracted from the skeleton pixels in the 2D image?

Comment: Read here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483105/matlab-code-for-finding-the-curvature-of-a-curve-using-given-data-points

Comment: @LWixson: The numpy array is the image I posted.

Comment: You could try a [circle hough transform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html) with a max radius equal to your cutoff radius of curvature, and look for peaks.

Comment: I found some possible algorithms listed in [this document](http://www.mi.auckland.ac.nz/DATA/CCV/books/KR/pdf-LectureNotes/22slides.pdf) and intend to try them out.

Comment: You can increase the quantization level of slope by increasing the square radius, for 3x3 square, yes it's true that it can only be 0,1,-1 and infinity, but for 5x5 square you can have other values, the more you increase the radius, the more quantization levels of slope you can obtain. you can estimate the slope at each point by linear regression of points within each operating window.

Answer (score 3):

An established way to do this is to fit a low-order parametric curve to each of the skeletonized points using two or more neighbouring points. Then you compute curvature at the point using the fitted curve parameters with an analytic formula. Several curve models can be used. The two main models are:

1. **A circle.** The radius of curvature, R is the reciprocal of the curvature. For a curve, it equals the radius of the circular arc which best approximates the curve at that point. You can fit a circle to a set of 2D data points using various methods. A python library that has implemented several is [here](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Least_Squares_Circle.html).
2. **A quadratic**. This can be fitted to the point and its neighbours, then curvature can be estimated through second-order differentiation of the curve [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature). You can use  `numpy.polyfit` to fit this model. A simple strategy is to first estimate the tangent vector at the point, by fitting  a local line (e.g. with polyfit using an order 1 curve). The you rotate the points to align the tangent vector  with the x axis. Finally you fit a 1D quadratic f(x) to the rotated points using polyfit.

The tricky thing with making any curvature estimator is that curvature can be estimated at different scales. For example, do I want my estimator to be sensitive to high frequency detail or is this actually noise? This decision manifests in the choice of neighbourhood size. Too small, and errors from noise and discretization lead to unstable estimates. However too large, and there may be large modelling error (error by approximating the curve as a parametric function). Generally you have to select the best neighbourhood size yourself.

You're also going to have some poor curvature estimates at junction points, but that's largely unavoidable as curvature is not well defined there. A naïve fix could be to segment all paths at junction points, and then estimate curvature on each path individually.

Answer (score 2):

Toby gave an excellent suggestion regarding junction points: detect the junction points and take each line in between those independently.

1. **Detecting junction points (and end points).** This is quite simple: all pixels that are set and have more than two neighbors are junction points. All pixels that are set and have exactly one neighbor are end points. Detect all those points and put their coordinates in a list.
2. **Finding the lines in between pairs of points.** Starting at each coordinate in your list, look for a line starting there. Note that for the junction points, you'll have at least three lines starting there. If you do this, you'll find each line two times. You can remove duplicates by reversing the lines that end to the left of where they start (and if the two end points are on the same image column, take the one on top as the start). Now they will be directly comparable, so you can delete the duplicates (or not store them in the first place). Note that just comparing start and end point is not sufficient as you can have different lines with the same start and end points.
3. **Tracing each line.** The step above requires that you trace each line. See if you can figure it out, it's fun! [Here is a description of an algorithm](http://www.crisluengo.net/index.php/archives/324) that traces the outline of objects, you can use it as inspiration as this problem is very similar. Store a vector with x-coordinates and one with y-coordinates for each line.
4. **Smoothing the lines.** As you noticed, consecutive steps are in one of 8 directions, so angles are strongly discretized. You can prevent this by smoothing the coordinate vectors. This is a quick-and-dirty trick, but it works. Think of these vectors as 1D images, and apply a smoothing filter (I prefer the Gaussian filter [for many reasons](http://www.crisluengo.net/index.php/archives/22)). Here you filter the vector with x-coordinates separately from the vector with y-coordinates.
5. **Computing the curvature.** Finally, you can compute the curvature of the curve, as the [norm of the derivative of the unit normal to the curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature). Don't forget to take the distance between points into account when computing derivatives!